# Передать содержимое файла через socket python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, websocket

**Server:**

```
import socket
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
soc.bind(('',8989))
soc.listen(1)

filename = 'dom4.txt'
with soc,open(filename,'wb') as file:
    while True:
        recvfile = soc.recv(4096)
        if not recvfile: break
        file.write(recvfile)
print("File has been received.")
```

**Client:**

```
import socket
soc = socket.socket()
soc.connect(('127.0.0.1',8989))
filename = 'dom.txt'
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    sendfile = file.read()
    soc.sendall(sendfile)
    print('file sent')
```

Не могу отправить содержимое файла не server, ошибка:

```
Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 57556)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server4.py", line 11, in <module>
    recvfile = soc.recv(4096)
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Что не так ?

Answer (score 0):

Server был написан некорректно, вот исправленный и рабочий вариант:

```
import socket
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
soc.bind(('',8989))
soc.listen(1)
con, addr = soc.accept()
filename = 'dom4.txt'
with open(filename,'wb') as file:
    while True:
        recvfile = con.recv(4096)
        if not recvfile: break
        file.write(recvfile)
print("File has been received.")
```